# List postgres services from pg_service.conf

Tags: python, postgresql, service, psycopg2

In postgres it's possible to use a [service connection file (pg_service.conf)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-pgservice.html) to define parameters like host, port, username, database name etc. in a central place.

I would like to present the user a list of all currently available services.

For a file `~/.pg_service.conf`

```
[test_db]
host=localhost
db=test

[production_db]
host=4.3.2.1
db=prod

[other_db]
host=localhost
db=other
```

That should be a list

- test_db
- production_db
- other_db

The configuration files for these services are resolved based on environment variables (`PGSERVICEFILE`, `PGSYSCONFDIR`), user directory, system configuration (`pg_config --sysconfdir`). If multiple files are present, apparently the services are merged with some precedence.

One could spend some time to implement some logic to do this lookup. But possibly there is some other way to do this? Something like

```
pg_config --list-services
```

I would also have psycopg2/python available. So something like the following would work as well

```
psycopg2.available_services()
```

What is the easiest (and most reliable) way to collect all available services defined on a system?

Comment: do you want to list all postgres instances runnning on OS?..

Comment: I think resolving this is done on client side. This file can define (multiple) local or remote services.

Comment: yes, but then I don't understand he question. 1. Is it possible to use pg_service.conf to define connection details? yes. 2. how to collect all services? running - from options probably. 3. how to collect all connection strings saved anywhere? grepping all files all the time

Comment: 1. Yes, it's possible to define connection details. 2. If the services are running is not important. 3. Yes, collect all the connection service names. There is no "time" component. It's for a configuration interface.

Comment: I hope the update with an example helps to clarify.